# Transparent cube with stroke only

Tags: three.js

In three.js How can I render a cube with no fill but only the edges?
For example:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to control the thickness of the lines you can use the `LineGeometry` class that's implemented in the THREE.js examples folder that creates triangle strips instead of GL.Lines to render.

See the following examples:

- https://threejs.org/examples/?q=line#webgl_lines_fat
- https://threejs.org/examples/?q=line#webgl_lines_fat_wireframe

Let me know if you need clarification and I can try to give a bit more detail.

### Edit

I've taken your example comment and modified it a bit here: https://jsfiddle.net/L21ozkdq/2/.

Here are the big things to keep in mind (they are called out in comments, as well):
- Import the LineGeometry example files.

- Create a LineGeometry object instead of BufferGeometry.
- Create a LineMaterial instead of LineBasicMaterial.
- Create a Line2 Object from the geometry and material.
- Create a positions array instead of an attribute for the LineGeometry.
- Create a box from a single line instead of many line segments in the position array.

Comment: Using the lines_fat_wireframe example I can get a cube with a stroke but it also has lines across each face, how can I avoid that? Code: https://pastebin.com/1m8VFpGc

Comment: The built in THREE box will have lines across each face because it's made of triangles. You'll have to create custom LineGeometry (like in the in catmull rom curve `webgl_lines_fat` example) with lines that only go along the edges of the cube.

Comment: I created the cube lines which works but the line width can't be changed due to a limitation with OpenGL. What can be done to get around this? Code: https://jsfiddle.net/rxcmhpfe/ Doc: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/LineBasicMaterial.linewidth

Comment: @Owen I've updated the answer with more details. You have to use the example scripts that extend THREE provided in the links I posted. Hope that helps!